# How to re-install GDAL library for Python 2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.7, gdal

I am trying to install the GDAL library for Python 2.7 and I have followed different available instructions such as

http://pythongisandstuff.wordpress.com/2011/07/07/installing-gdal-and-ogr-for-python-on-windows/#comment-181

Unfortunately, I was not successful up to now and faced a lot of difficulties. I would like to remove all the installed files and re-install the GDAL library one more time. To be honest, I am afraid that I may remove something by mistake therefore I would like to have your guidance to help me with which steps I should do to remove the installation and start from scratch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is the best source you can find for python libraries pre-compiled for windows..

http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#gdal

download the version you want and enjoy..

Comment: : Thank you very much for your help and guidance. I should say the last that installed GDAL ,I used the same link but unfortunately it was not successful. the installation would go well but when I type for instance **from osgeo import gdal** it would fail.

Comment: : any idea how to solve the problem?!!!. well I would like to remove all the installed files and re-install the GDAL library one more time.I would like to have your guidance to help me which steps I should do to remove the installation and start from scratch.

Comment: ohk, lets finish this, tell me the process how you are installing it.. are you using easy_install ?? or are you using the source that i provided??

Comment: Also note the warning on Gohlke's site that the installer no longer works on Win XP.

Comment: @ abhishekgarg:  Thank you very much for your guidance and consideration. sorry for my delay ,I had some internet connection problem. Well, the steps I have been through were : 1. Get the GDAL core files1.
2. Get the Python bindings
3. Install GDAL
4. Edit Environment Variables
5. Install Python bindings  . and at the end I test the code **‘ogr2ogr’**  which was working and then **from osgeo import gdal** which did not work and say gdal does not exist.
2. Get the Python bindings
3. Install GDAL
4. Edit Environment Variables
5. Install Python bindings

Comment: thank you, I have started now to apply your approach. I would inform you about the result ;)

Answer (score -1):

ohk, looks like i got it working by following the same method.. 
try this...

1. download [this](http://download.osgeo.org/gdal/win32/1.7/gdalwin32geor170.zip) and unzip it and keep the gdalwin32-1.7 in c drive (or any other folder where you want it to),
2. then download [this](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/fo6ywpc8/GDAL-1.10.0.win32-py2.7.exe) and install it.
3. create a folder inside the gdalwin32 in c drive called data,
4. update your system environment variables, add 
   `C:\gdalwin32-1.7\bin` in path 
    and new varible called `GDAL_DATA` with value `C:\gdalwin32-1.7\data`.

and thats it.
it working on my computer..

Comment: I followed your instruction step by step.  first download the both files . then unzipped the 'gdalwin32geor170' under c:\ drive and installed the 'GDAL-1.10.0.win32-py2.7' . The set the environment as ** path: C:\gdalwin32geor170\gdalwin32-1.7\bin** and GDAL_DATA : C:\gdalwin32geor170\data.  but when I type ** from osgeo import gdal**  it says that dll failed. what do you think is the reason for that :(

Comment: you might be doing something wrong with system environment.. 
open cmd, type and do this ....

`set path=%PATH%;C:\gdalwin32-1.7\bin`
`set GDAL_DATA=C:\gdalwin32-1.7\data`
`python`
`from osgeo import gdal`

open the python interpreter in the same commandline and test it.. it works for me every time.. try it and let me know.

Comment: well I would say I am 95% sure that I have not done any mistake. Well, I can say even before I have done pretty much the same but still no progress. I changed the environment on the environment setting at GUI. but this time I tried as you said in the cmd.  ok here I have to confirm that 'set path=%PATH%;C:\gdalwin32-1.7\bin'  and 'set GDAL_DATA=C:\gdalwin32-1.7\data' are typed in two different line in cmd.  then what about the following 'python from osgeo import gdal' ?

Comment: no they are four commands that you have to type separately.. in the same cmd console.. `python` will open the python interpreter in the same cmd environment.

Comment: well the first two line was alright but when I typed python, it could not recognized that though it is there

Comment: then it means that your python directory is not set in your system environments. instead of just `python` type `"C:\Python27\python.exe"`

Comment: also it would be very good if you add python paths into your environment varibles..

Comment: I have gone through from scratch. even set the new environment for python. well previously it was on the path for specific user and now I made it for the whole system. but still it fails. it seems to me based on the error that it goes through **osgeo** but cannot find specific module there. just one question, the data folder that we make is empty ,right?  so what do you think I can do more right now ?

Comment: do you think there is some problem with my system maybe?!

Comment: you can add me on gmail hakkahnoodle@gmail.com

Comment: this is perfect. I really appreciate your consideration.